# How to use shared scope in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, custom-scope, intellij-inspections

As PhpStorm has mentioned that we can create 2 types of scope: local & shared.

How to use Shared scope for multiple developers??

Answer (score 3):

**Local scope** is saved in `.idea/workspace.xml` file which is user-specific and therefore available for current user only.

Each **Shared scope** is saved into separate config file (in `.idea/scopes` folder) and therefore can be shared with the rest of your team via VCS (if you share `.idea` together with the project code) or some other means (where you can sync files across multiple computers).

---

A bit on VCS sharing of `.idea` folder: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839